# Flex 4.5 preloader (swf download progress bar) is not showing up

Tags: apache-flex, preloader, flex-spark

In flex 4.0/4.1, there is always the application preloader. (swf download progress bar) I just upgraded to flex 4.5 SDK, and I immediately noticed that the preloader is gone. Anyone noticed that? I double checked by going back to 4.0 again, and confirmed that it showed up correctly in 4.0 and 4.1, but not in 4.5. I am working on flex for regular computers, not for mobile.

After digging around the problem, I notice that if I do:

```
preloader="mx.preloaders.SparkDownloadProgressBar"
```

The preloader does NOT show up.
If I use the older version of preloader like:

```
preloader="mx.preloaders.DownloadProgressBar"
```

The preloader does show up, but I do want to use the newer version of preloader.

Comment: Why would you specify the preloader if it's already added by default?  You're not doing a custom preloader...

Comment: @J_A_X He's saying that the preloader isn't added by default in 4.5. That's what he's trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ya, the preloader didn't show up by default, that's why I was trying to explicitly set it, but still doesn't work. Can you guy also test it too? Or I have uploaded my compiled swf, you can also test run at your side to see if it show up. http://www.mediafire.com/?2zoh45lt6pb5abh

Comment: Is it possible that Adobe changed it to not show the preloader if you already have cached all the flex SWF/SWZ files on your computer?  Can you remove your cache and try again? (This is speculation, as I'm currently programming in 4.0 and we haven't moved to 4.5 yet).